# サーバ上でlaravelのsandbox環境を作成したい

Tags: laravel-5

・達成したいこと
1つしかないバーチャルホストで、別の作業ディレクトリの作業動作を確認できるようにしたい

・状況
SSH接続しサーバ上での作業しています。
プロジェクトの開発をしているのですが、別に学習用のsandboxディレクトリを作成しました。
現状一つしかないバーチャルホストで作業しているので、ブラウザ上で確認するときは同じものを使用できるようにsandboxはシンボリックリンクしてあります。
`ls -l`で確認すると`XXX->sandbox`と表示されるのでリンクは正しくできていると思います。

プロジェクト開発に使用しているディレクトリは、リモートからcloneしてきたもの。
sandboxディレクトリはサーバ上、ターミナル（Teraterm）を使用し、一からlaravelをインストールしました。

・いじったファイル
 1. 開発環境構築時に行ったので必要かと思い`cp .env.example .env`実行し、APP_URLをバーチャルホストに変更
 2. 同じく`cp .env.example .env`実行後、DB_HOSTがlocalになっていたのでサーバのIPアドレスに変更

いざバーチャルホストに接続すると
'UnexpectedValueException
The stream or file "/home/hogehoge/sandbox/storage/logs/laravel-2019-02-12.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied'

と出てしまいました。なにがいけないのでしょうか？
ローカルでやった時のようなwelcomeページを開くにはどの手順が足りていないのでしょうか？

Windows10/Teraterm/Laravel5.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ls -l`コマンドで権限を確認したところ読みしか権限がなかったので、それが原因かと思い権限を広げることにしました。

`chmod -Rc 777 storage`
を実行し、無事にlaravelのwelcomeページにたどり着きました。

laravelのトラブルではなく権限のエラーでした。